# Calculate correlation of data generated by function in R

Tags: r, dataset, time-series, correlation, random-walk

I have created the following function in **R**:

```
timeseriesmodel <- function(N, x0, delta, variance) {
      z<-cumsum(rnorm(n=N, mean=0, sd=sqrt(variance)))
      t<-1:N
      x<-x0+t*delta+z
      return(x)}
```

This function returns a vector 'x' of length 'N', representing the data points of a random walk with drift.

In my case:

```
timeseriesmodel(250,1,0,1.2)
```

Now I should repeat this function 100 times, ending up with 100 timeseries data sets of length 250. Then I have to estimate the correlation between the 249th and 250th value of the dataset 'x', using the 100 sets.

As an inexperienced user of **R**, I don't see how to manipulate the data effectively and calculate/estimate the correlation of the requested data points. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work for `replicate`

```
> set.seed(1)
> Series <- replicate(100, timeseriesmodel(250,1,0,1.2) )  # repeating 100 times `timeseriesmodel`
> dim(Series)   # each result is store column-wise
[1] 250 100
> cor(Series[249,], Series[250,] ) # here's the correlation between element 249 and 250
[1] 0.9975532
```