# Generate Random Walk with Drift and/or Trend in R

Tags: r, trend, random-walk, drift

Generating a Random Walk in R is pretty easy. It's done by the following code:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- cumsum(x)
```

But how do I generate/simulate a Random Walk with Trend and / or Drift?

Comment: how about `cumsum(x+d)`, where `d` is the drift per step???

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162429/calculate-correlation-of-data-generated-by-function-in-r) is not identical to yours, but happens to answer your question.

Comment: Just add an increasing function to that series. I don't see how that is at all difficult.

Comment: You should probably post your answer as such. It seems reasonably compact but would need an explanation to avoid the "no code only answers" censoring police.

Comment: OK, when I get around to it (anyone else is free to do so, or copy from the linked question, in the meantime)

Comment: Don't quite understand why q. was closed -- I could appreciate "too simple", "almost a duplicate" ... but unreproducible or typographical error?

Answer (score 6):

A slightly more compact/efficient version of the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162429/calculate-correlation-of-data-generated-by-function-in-r):

```
cumsum(rnorm(n=100, mean=drift, sd=sqrt(variance)))
```

should give you a realization of a random walk with variance `t*variance` and mean `t*drift`, where `t` is the index (starting from 1; prepend a zero or add a constant to the whole series if you like).

Comment: Ummm. Where does the `t` come in? Do you mean `n`?

Comment: `t` is the series index (i.e. `t=1:n`)